# FirebaseListObservable not get filled

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, ngfor

I am making an angular test project with firebase data. The problem I am facing is to show the data in my firebase database. I can push data to the database but I can't see the data in my page. I use angularfire2 in my angular project. I seem to miss something, but I can't figure out what. Below is my code.

this is my component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

msg: string = '';
constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.items = af.list('/messages');
}

send(message: string) {
  this.items.push({ message: message });
  this.msg = '';
}
}
```

and this is my html

```
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send now" (click)="send(message.value)">
  <div class="details-container" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-9 columns">
        <p> {{ item.message }} </p>
       </div>
      <div class="medium-3 columns">
        <button>delete</button>
        <button>edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And this is data from my firebase database [image]

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: @R.Richards yes i get these 2 errors:
- Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
-ErrorContext: DebugContext

Comment: what if you declare items as a normal Observable?

Comment: @DanielArechiga gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on a limb here but I'm thinking Angular does not understand the async pipe because what you have as "items" is not an `Observable`, so call `.valueChanges()` after the list method.

please Refer to https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md for a good explanation of how `valueChanges()` works in your situation.

I see some key differences in the docs above and what you have there, in the docs "items" is declared as an `Observable` because the list method returns a `AngularFireList` which is not even an Array.

Now if you need to treat items as an Array then convert your list to observable like so: `this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();` and subscribe to it and fill whatever array you want, although that seems kind of redundant to me when  you can use the async pipe.

Comment: even reacreating the angularfire exmaple does not work